# Will git pull override a file I have been editing?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

Suppose I am editing a file which is under version control with git, and whilst I am editing it, another collaborator also edits that file, and commits his changes. I will then need to update my local repository before committing my changes. So, I save and close the file, and pull the latest changes. Will this override my file, deleting all my changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will `fetch` but not `merge` because your working directory is not clean.

You could test this safely by:

```
git stash            # saves your uncommitted changes to the stash
git stash apply      # applies (but does not pop) latest stash
git pull             # will fail
```

Typically you will want to do

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 2):

**No.**
It will make you merge the two files by hand if there is a conflict.

Here's a doc about resolivng a merge conflict if one should occur. 
https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/